# React Component is not re-rendering on the first state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a very simple survey. The kind that you reply by Yes or No. I have made a list of questions that I have put and extracted in its own file (QuestionsList.js).

Here is my question list:

```
const QuestionsList = [
"Do you believe in ghosts? ",
"Have you ever seen a UFO? ",
"Can cats jump six times their length? "
]
export default QuestionsList
```

I have my App:

```
import './App.css';
import Question from './components/Question';
import QuestionsList from './QuestionsList'
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  let questionsList = QuestionsList
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(null)
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([])
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false)

  const onStartHandler = () => {
    setIsStarted(true)
    updateCurrentQuestion()
  }

  const updateCurrentQuestion = () => {
    setCurrentQuestion(questionsList[current])
  }

  const onYesHandler = () => {
    setCurrent(current => current += 1)
    setAnswers([...answers, 1])
    updateCurrentQuestion()
  }
  const onNoHandler = () => {
    setCurrent(current => current += 1)
    setAnswers([...answers, 0])
    updateCurrentQuestion()
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isStarted ? <Question question={currentQuestion} onYes={onYesHandler} onNo={onNoHandler} /> : null}
      <button onClick={onStartHandler}>START!</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(`Current: ${current}\nCurrent Question: ${currentQuestion}\nAnswers: ${answers}`)}>STATE LOG</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my Question component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Question = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{props.question}</h2>
            <div>
                <button onClick={props.onYes}>YES</button>
                <button onClick={props.onNo}>NO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Question
```

The problem is that whenever I launch the app. The first question shows up, but on the very FIRST click on YES or NO, the state changes and so does the question, but the FIRST click, does not rerender the question. However, every subsequent click does re-render the component. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setCurrentQuestion()` it uses the previous value of `current` because setting the state (which `setCurrent` does) is async.

You don't need the `currentQuestion` state, because it's derived from `current`. Use the `current` value to get the question from the `questionsList`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Question = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{props.question}</h2>
            <div>
                <button onClick={props.onYes}>YES</button>
                <button onClick={props.onNo}>NO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

function App({ questionsList }) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([])
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false)

  const onStartHandler = () => {
    setIsStarted(true)
  }

  const onYesHandler = () => {
    setCurrent(current => current += 1)
    setAnswers([...answers, 1])
  }
  const onNoHandler = () => {
    setCurrent(current => current += 1)
    setAnswers([...answers, 0])
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isStarted ? (
        <Question 
          question={questionsList[current]}
          onYes={onYesHandler}
          onNo={onNoHandler} />
        )
        :
        (
          <button onClick={onStartHandler}>START!</button>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const QuestionsList = [
  "Do you believe in ghosts? ",
  "Have you ever seen a UFO? ",
  "Can cats jump six times their length? "
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App questionsList={QuestionsList} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const updateCurrentQuestion = (num) => {
    setCurrentQuestion(questionsList[num])
  }
   // within no/yes functions
   let num = current;
   setCurrent(old => old + 1);
   updateCurrentQuestion(num);
```

This should fix it. UpdateCurrentQuestion is getting past state.

Answer (score 0):

### Set initial state

the simple solution:

replace this
`const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(null)`

in this `const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(questionsList[current])`

---

BTW
I see some things to improve.

- the `onYesHandler` `onNoHandler` can be one function that get boolean (true or false for yes or no)
- You don't need to save the data you import `let questionsList = QuestionsList`. you can use it from the import as `QuestionsList`

but it's looks ok for a beginner :)